# How to get user names and pictures of people leaving comments on a Facebook page you manage?

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

The field "from" returns nothing in this query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/(page id)?fields=posts{comments{message,created_time,from}}&access_token=(page access token)
```

The other fields return what I expect.
I'm administrator of the page but I haven't submitted my app for review because according to this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-default) I don't have too, or am I wrong?

> From the page:
>
> Does not require App Review.
>
> Grants your app access to the default fields of the User object that
>   are a subset of a person's public profile:
>
> id 
>   first_name
>   last_name
>   middle_name
>   name
>   name_format
>   picture
>   short_name

Or is there anything else I could have done wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. What you are referring to, is about the basic permission a user grants your app by logging in to it. But the users merely commenting on your page have not done any such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without authorization, you cannot get any user specific data anymore, no matter if you own the Page in question. You can only get data like the message or the link to facebook.com.

Comment: I'm actually the only user of this app. The purpose of this app is to get the posts on our page and present them live on TV. Guess I a have to find another approach then. Thanx for your time @luschn

Comment: yeah, in that case it´s not possible at all. showing it live on a TV means that you would show users and their pictures somewhere else than on facebook, that would most likely be a privacy issue anyway...

Comment: in other words: if i comment something on facebook, i would not want to show up on some tv screen that i don´t know about. :)

Comment: You wouldn’t! We ask people to comment on specific topics and will only use comments related to the show - audience engagement :)